SSAS 2019 User Access Discrepancy Between http Access over IIS and direct access of SSAS
Problem:
I have configured SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) 2019 on Server A. User "U" is granted access to only 2 out of 5 databases through role membership.
Setup:
Server A: Windows Server with SSAS 2019 (HTTP access enabled via IIS 10).(Guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0)
Server B: Windows Server with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
Observed Behavior:
When connecting to SSAS on Server A via SSMS on Server B using server name (e.g., server_name_a\olap), User U can only access the assigned 2 databases (Correct Behavior).
However, when connecting via HTTP (http://server_name_a/OLAP/msmdpump.dll), User U gains access to all 5 databases, bypassing role restrictions (Incorrect Behavior).
Desired Outcome:
User U should only access the assigned 2 databases regardless of the connection method (Windows or Basic Authentication) in SSMS.
